# Discord.js - Making a Wikipedia fandom search command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i want to make a Wikipedia fandom command for my bot which searches articles from a specific Wikipedia fandom page but don't know how can I get any information about how I can do that? searching on YouTube or Google didn't help and didn't get any results

Comment: There is a [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a couple places on their forums saying they have an outdated API of which I could not find any docs on, so with some more digging into that you might be able to use that with axios or any other HTTP request module. Or you have the option of looking at how they structure their data on webpages and write a small webscraper script depending on exactly what information you want to extract.

An alternative would be to supply the user with a link to the page using an Embed, either way hope this helps.

**Edit:**
Someone in the comments says there is an API so check that out first